# Finding instances of pairs of tuples in a table, column names are the same for one column, and for another column?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Let's say I have a table called "TRANSIT", with the the columns (city_name, highway_name), and it tells you what highways that go through a city.

Using Relational Algebra (or SQL if that is easier, and i can translate it to RA), I want to select all pairs of highways, which go through atleast two cities together, for instance, if there is Highway A, and Highway B, and they both go City A and City B, I want to select those two highways

What I have so far, is only selecting pairs of highways, that go through one city together:

```
πC1.highway_name, C2.highway_name (σ C1.highway_name = C2.highway_name (σ C1.city_name ≠ C2.city_name ( ρ C1 (TRANSIT) X (ρ C2 (TRANSIT)))))
```

However, I need it so that it returns c1.highway_name, c2.highway_name which go through two or more cities together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can count the number of cities that two highways share using `join` and `group by`:

```
select hc1.highway, hc2.highway, count(*) as NumInCommon
from highwaycity hc1 join
     highwaycity hc2
     on hc1.city = hc2.city and
        hc1.highway < hc2.highway
group by hc1.highway, hc2.highway
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Good luck translating this to the notation of relational algebra.

Comment: cool thanks for that, I guess you can't really use count in RA, but I managed to find a solution, using 3 cartesian products, instead of one